# Complex add/subtract time with SlickSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

I'm using SlickSlider (just for the UI/UX) to add or rest time as a Tachymetre.

The basis is simple:

- 2 SlickSliders with different time values each one.
- 1 DIV element that shows the total time depending which slider is selected.

the complex part is making this real. I barely know jQuery and JavaScript but I don't know how to mess with time values (like 3600 secs, sum minutes, etc.)

This is what I've got so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var TimeTotal = "00:00:000"; //min:sec:dec
  
  $('.slider-a').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
    fade: false
  });
  
  $('.slider-b').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
    fade: false
  });
  
  function evaluateChecked () {
        if ($("this slider-a").is('active')) {
            TimeTotal = Number(TimeTotal) + Number($("this slider").val());
            $('.total').text("Total: " + TimeTotal);
        } else {
            TimeTotal = Number(TimeTotal) - Number($("this slider").val());
            $('.total').text("Total: " + TimeTotal);
        }
  };
  function evaluateChecked () {
        if ($("this slider-b").is('active')) {
            TimeTotal = Number(TimeTotal) + Number($("this slider").val());
            $('.total').text("Total: " + TimeTotal);
        } else {
            TimeTotal = Number(TimeTotal) - Number($("this slider").val());
            $('.total').text("Total: " + TimeTotal);
        }
   };  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.7/slick.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css" />

<div class="slider-a">
  Set Timer at:
  <div>
    <h1 class="index-header" value="01:21:950">Slide A1</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1 class="index-header" value="01:56:250">Slide A2</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1 class="index-header" value="00:40:750">Slide A3</h1>
  </div>
</div>

plus/minus:

<div class="slider-b">
  <div>
    <h1 class="index-header" value="-00:30:000">Slide B1</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1 class="index-header" value="01:00:000">Slide B2</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1 class="index-header" value="00:00:400">Slide B3</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="total"></div>
```

I know I'm making this wrong, don't be mean because I'm learning with this.
Your help is very appreciated!

Comment: I thought making the SlickSlider "active" element as radio buttons as a possible option, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work. `evaluateChecked ()` was pasted twice and has no closing curly bracket `}`. Even that fixed. It does nothing. Can you edit?